# Can I refund my skill purchases?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

When I am investing points into my skills I assume that this is permanent.

Can you sell and rebuy skills to essentially respect your character? Or is it a matter of just grinding out more points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not refund your skill points. You do have grind.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, Ubisoft didn't implement a resetting or selling skill points feature.

If there's a skill that you really really want you'll have to **Grind** or just **perform Co-Op Missions or Missions you haven't done before** and most of those will provide you with skill points.

To Grind just go out into Paris and **get into fights**, **solve murders**, **solve Crowd Events** (**Tackling Thieves** and **Killing Criminals**) and you will get a lot of Creed Points to get Skill Points.

Comment: Creed points and skill points are not the same. Creed points are used to upgrade gear.

Comment: I know. But evolving your assassin requires Creed Points to level up. Almost like an exp bar

Comment: and in my answer I dont say that they are the same.

Comment: Ah must be a typo!